# How do I stop Python from escaping the backslashes when reading text from a file?

Tags: python, text, escaping

I'm having trouble getting text from a file to be in the same format as the text in a string. Example:

```
>>> a = 'Hello\tWorld'
>>> list(a)
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\t', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

That's fine.
Now when I read the same characters from a file, I get a different result...

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    a = f.read()

>>> list(a)
['H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\\', 't', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

The tab is gone. Now I have an escaped backshlash and a t, instead of a tab. And the number of elements in the list is different.

How do I read a file, and keep the tab?

BTW, I'm working on character counting and would like to be counting tabs as one thing, not two.

Comment: There was never a tab to begin with. `\t` is a special digraph for string *literals*. The text file itself only contains ``\`` and `t`. If you want to treat that as a tab, it's your responsibility to replace with a tab after reading the pair from the file.

Comment: In the second case `a` becomes a raw input. The second version is reproduced by setting `a = r'Hello\tWorld' ` before calling `list(a)`.